# Battery status in menu bar was red having charged my laptop for one hour

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

The red battery status color stayed there for about 40 seconds, then went back to black.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the menubar took some seconds to refresh after the computer was sleeping especially after the computer runs out of charge. 
If you have doubts about the health of your battery you could use this amazing app to check it https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/